# Wireshark capture Arduino FTDI USB traffic in order to debug applications that talk to the arduino

Tags: arduino, usb, wireshark

I use arduino UNO with ATMEGA16U2 running as FTDI chip. Furthermore According to wireshark's [instructions](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) I enabled the USB monitoring for wireshark as well.

Also over my GNU/Linux Machine the `lsusb` command outputs:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
```

So on wireshark I selected `usbmon1` interface but in this interface also is connected the usb mouse so I get heaps of traffic so I filter it out with: `usb.addr==2341:0043` but when I do I get no traffic at all why that happens?

PS I use the sketch from [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/52241/43808) answer with `screen` GNU/Linux command.

What I try to achieve is to find out the USB traffic that goes from and to the arduino in order to be able to debug easily the software that send and receives data from arduino. Therefore I want to be able to filter this traffic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about local USB communication between a PC and PC peripheral, and as a result **the question asked is not in any way about the Internet of Things.**  As a matter of practical advice it's also a pointless path of inquiry - as the USB implementation is long proven, what you want to look at is the data carried over the virtual serial channel, not the raw USB encapsulation.

Comment: It's also a bit problematic that you are re-posting this after having originally posted it on an other SE site. That posting got some feedback pointing out one of the procedural mistakes in your method, which in deleting and reposting on an even less appropriate site you seem to now ignore - if you delete people's advice, you're unlikely to receive any more help.